# Handling multiple states in swift

Tags: ios, swift, architecture, state

I have a tableview which needs to handle 9 different states.
I have two sections which contains different data models (A, B)
These two sections have logic dependent of each other

```
1) !A.isEmpty
2) !B.isEmpty
3) A show expandable footer (A.count > 5)
4) B show expandable footer (B.count > 5)
5) A shows collapsable footer (user clicked on A.expandable footer)
6) B shows collapsable footer (user clicked on B.expandable footer
7) A.count > 3 && B.isEmpty
8) B.count > 3 && A.isEmpty
9) A.count > 3 && B.isEmpty && A shows collapsable footer (user clicked on A.expandable footer)
```

Is there a standard to handle multiple states? I am thinking of creating a state struct of some sorts.. What is the "Industry standard" to handling this problem?

This is what I am currently using -- Many computation variables

```
let numberOfCells = 5
var A.expanded = false
var B.expanded = false
var A = [Data]()
var B = [Data]()
var state5 = A.expanded
var state6 = B.expanded

var A.showFooter: Bool {
    return A.count > numberOfCells
}
var B.showFooter: Bool {
    return B.count > numberOfCells
}
var state7: Bool {
    return A.showFooter && B.isEmpty
}
var state8: Bool {
    return A.isEmpty && B.showFooter
}
var state9: Bool {
    return (state7 && state6)
        || (state8 && state5)
}
```

Comment: have you had a look at bitmasks?  You could have a single variable with 9 bits to store everything, and then you can check each bit separately.  There are lots of tutorials out there which should get you started

Comment: @Russell That's actually a really good idea! Thanks I think I will try to implement that.

Comment: You have a free state machine in gameplaykit and it will save you a lot of efforts.

Comment: @E.Coms Interesting.. Although it might be a bit overkill for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think an enum or struct would suit your needs.

```
struct Video {
enum State {
    case willDownload(from: URL)
    case downloading(task: Task)
    case playing(file: File, progress: Double)
    case paused(file: File, progress: Double)
}

var state: State
```

}

```
    private func resolveActionButtonImage() -> UIImage {
    // The image for the action button is declaratively resolved
    // directly from the video state
    switch video.state {
        // We can easily discard associated values that we don't need
        // by simply omitting them
        case .willDownload:
            return .wait
        case .downloading:
            return .cancel
        case .playing:
            return .pause
        case .paused:  
            return .play
    } 
}
```

}

Reference:
https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/modelling-state-in-swift

Comment: How do I handle multiple states? For instance, my Video would have willDownload and paused. And the resolveActionButtonImage needs to handle both cases.

Comment: If the two data models are related to each other, I believe the solution might be to simplify your data model and group them together. However, if the models generally stand alone, but you only need the logic for one view controller, create a class object that takes both models and parses the information you need to avoid bloating your View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to use an object to hold the logic and bitmasking to act as the states.

```
private struct StateModel: OptionSet {
    let rawValue: Int

    static let AIsEmpty = StateModel(rawValue: 1 << 0)
    static let AHasValues = StateModel(rawValue: 1 << 1)
    static let BIsEmpty = StateModel(rawValue: 1 << 2)
    static let BHasValues = StateModel(rawValue: 1 << 3)
    static let AFooterIsVisible = StateModel(rawValue: 1 << 4)
    static let BIsVisible = StateModel(rawValue: 1 << 5)
    static let AFooterIsExpanded = StateModel(rawValue: 1 << 6)
    static let BFooterIsExpanded = StateModel(rawValue: 1 << 7)
    static let AFooterShowsCTA: StateModel = [.AHasValues, .BIsEmpty]
    static let BFooterShowCTA: StateModel = [.AIsEmpty, .BHasValues]
    static let ACTAAsCell: StateModel = [.AFooterShowsCTA, .AFooterIsVisible]
    static let BCTAAsCell: StateModel = [.BFooterShowCTA, .BFooterIsExpanded]
}

class Logic {

var stateModel: StateModel = []

//Should AFooter show CTA?
var showAFooter: Bool {
  stateModel.contains(.AFooterShowsCTA)
}

}
```